# Add class attributes if another class attribute match the other in a list

Tags: python, list, class, list-comprehension

I have a class such has:

```
class ex(object):

    def __init__(self, tag, quantity):
        self.tag = tag
        self.quantity = quantity
```

I also have a list with multiple instance of this class such has:

```
[ex('a', 10.5), ex('b', 5.0),  ex('c', 2.0), ex('a', 5.0), ex('c', -10.0)]
```

I am trying to figure out a nice way to add the self.quantiy attribute if the self.tag matches another instance in the list.

output would be :

```
[ex('a', 15.5), ex('b', 5.0),  ex('c', -8.0)]
```

thanks

edit: final instance can be a new instance or the first of the list accumulated. the max size of the list will be around len() of 1000

Comment: Do you want new instances created, or modify existing instances?

Comment: How big might this list get? Is an O(n^2) solution acceptable?

Comment: both ways or okay, I prefer a new instance

Comment: O(n^2) would be alright, I dont see list over 1k of len

Comment: Why do you "hope" for a list comprehension?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I like 1 liner, but to be honest it doesnt really matter :)

Comment: @StevenG Liking one-liners is a bad reason to use a list comprehension. You should use list comprehensions for their use-cases, and when they are readable, or else use an equivalent for-loop. In any event, does the order of the resulting list matter?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga no, order doesnt matter, also: I understand your point, fixing question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a plain loop is actually better choice than a list comprehension here.  It is possible in O(n) complexity by keeping track of tags already seen:

```
seen = {}

for instance in in_list:
    try:
        existing = seen[instance.tag]
    except KeyError:
        seen[instance.tag] = instance
    else:
        existing.quantity += instance.quantity

out_list = list(seen.values())  # can drop the "list" call on Python 2.x
```

The first instance from each group will be used, and updated afterward if the tag is seen again.

If you wish to preserve original ordering of the tags, then drop in a `collections.OrderedDict` for the `seen` variable instead of a plain dict.  There will be a slight performance penalty, yet the solution remains O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

`O(n^2)`, but simpler code.

```
class ex(object):
    def __init__(self, tag, quantity):
        self.tag = tag
        self.quantity = quantity

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r, %r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.tag, self.quantity)

exes = [ex('a', 10.5), ex('b', 5.0), ex('c', 2.0), ex('a', 5.0), ex('c', -10.0)]
summed_exes = [ex(tag, sum(e.quantity for e in exes if e.tag == tag))
               for tag in sorted({e.tag for e in exes})]
print(summed_exes)
```

`sorted` is optional.

Output:

```
[ex('a', 15.5), ex('b', 5.0), ex('c', -8.0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n) solution creating new objects:

```
In [9]: class Ex(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, tag, quantity):
   ...:         self.tag = tag
   ...:         self.quantity = quantity
   ...:
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return '%s(%r, %r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.tag, self.quantity)
   ...:

In [10]: objs = [Ex('a', 10.5), Ex('b', 5.0),  Ex('c', 2.0), Ex('a', 5.0), Ex('c', -10.0)]

In [11]: objs
Out[11]: [Ex('a', 10.5), Ex('b', 5.0), Ex('c', 2.0), Ex('a', 5.0), Ex('c', -10.0)]

In [12]: grouped = {}

In [13]: for obj in objs:
    ...:     grouped[obj.tag] = grouped.get(obj.tag, 0) + obj.quantity
    ...:

In [14]: new_objs = [Ex(k, v) for k,v in grouped.items()]

In [15]: new_objs
Out[15]: [Ex('b', 5.0), Ex('a', 15.5), Ex('c', -8.0)]
```

You could get fancier using a `defaultdict` or a `Counter`, or an `OrderedDict` if order matters.